# Security query on Unicode encoding in HTTP header vs HTML

Tags: security, http, character-encoding

According to OWASP the server should specify the Unicode encoding for all communications. I have read this can be set in the HTTP header, as well as in HTML. Best practice is to set it in the header by default but allow it to be overriden in HTML.

My question is, if the server sets the Unicode encoding in the header, and the client responds with the encoding in the header, but maliciously injects a different encoding in the HTML, will the server reject it or would this be down to the application to detect? Maybe this is a server specific question...

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "client responds"?

Comment: Sorry, rephrase that to 'when the client communicates with the server, it will also include the encoding in the header'.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP `Content-Type` header overrides the `<meta charset>`.

This is [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#encodings) in section 5.2.2 of the HTML spec:

> conforming user agents must observe the following priorities when determining a document's character encoding (from highest priority to lowest):
>
> - An HTTP "charset" parameter in a "Content-Type" field.
> - A META declaration with "http-equiv" set to "Content-Type" and a value set for "charset".
> - [...]

Comment: According to: 
http://www.webstandards.org/learn/articles/askw3c/dec2002/ 

The HTML overrides the Header so doc authors can set it themselves?
"Best. The character encoding is properly set at the server level, either with a default that authors can override or on a per-document basis"

Comment: The "Best" solution is talking about giving the author a way to override the default choice of HTTP header (eg using an Apache `.htaccess` file), not with a `meta charset` in the document itself. Look a bit further up to "user agents will try, in this order: ..." to clarify.